# Idiom/word for seeming misleadingly encouraging

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word to use in the following sentence:

> Upon deeper contemplation, the news struck me as a ______ warning.

I’m trying to say that the news isn’t being perceived as a warning, because it is superficially innocuous/encouraging.

Comment: How can news have an "appearance"?

Answer (score 3):

That would be a ***veiled** warning*.

Here's the relevant definition *veiled* from the OED, with a couple of usage examples:

> **veiled**, *adj.*
> **2.** *figurative*. Of immaterial things.
>  **b.**  Not openly declared, expressed, or stated; implied or inferred. Also: covert,
> disguised.
>  <sub>1934   *Stevens Point (Wisconsin) Daily
> Jrnl.* 8 May (City ed.) 1/7   His statement..carried a veiled
> warning that if anything happened to him because of his imprisonment
> the government would be held responsible.
>  2015   *Guardian*
> (Nexis) 22 June   It was hard to know whether the comments..were
> a joke or a veiled threat.
>  Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression ***in disguise***:

> Upon deeper contemplation, the news struck me as ***a warning in disguise***.

or

> Upon deeper contemplation, the news struck me as ***a desguised warning***.

***To  disguise*** means

> to give a new appearance to a person or thing, especially in order to
> hide its true form.
> If people, objects, or activities are in disguise, they appear to be something that they are not, especially intentionally:
>
> - He claims that most Western aid to the Third World is just ***colonialism in disguise***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disguise))

Comment: That doesn't fit in the blank.

Answer (score -1):

A *pseudo* warning?

**pseudo** [soo-doh]
adjective;
*not actually but having the appearance of; pretended; false or spurious; sham.*